# Buffering Incomplete High Speed Reads

Tags: c++, serial-port, buffer

I am reading data ~100 bytes at 100hz from a serial port.  My buffer is 1024 bytes, so often my buffer doesn't get completely used.  Sometimes however, I get hiccups from the serial port and the buffer gets filled up.

My data is organized as a [header]data[checksum].  When my buffer gets filled up, sometimes a message/data is split across two reads from the serial port.

This is a simple problem, and I'm sure there are a lot of different approaches.  I am ahead of schedule so I would like to research different approaches.  Could you guys name some paradigms that cover buffering in high speed data that might need to be put together from two reads?  Note, the main difference I see in this problem from say other buffering I've done (image acquisition, tcp/ip), is that there we are guaranteed full packets/messages.  Here a "packet" may be split between reads, which we will only know once we start parsing the data.

Oh yes, note that the data buffered in from the read has to be parsed, so to make things simple, the data should be contiguous when it reaches the parsing.  (Plus I don't think that's the parser's responsibility)

Some Ideas I Had:

1. Carry over unused bytes to my original buffer, then fill it with the read after the left over bytes from the previous read. (For example, we read 1024 bytes, 24 bytes are left at the end, they're a partial message, memcpy to the beginning of the read_buffer_, pass the beginning + 24 to read and read in 1024 - 24)
2. Create my own class that just gets blocks of data.  It has two pointers, read/write and a large chunk of memory (1024 * 4).  When you pass in the data, the class updates the write pointer correctly, wraps around to the beginning of its buffer when it reaches the end.  I guess like a ring buffer?
3. I was thinking maybe using a `std::vector<unsigned char>`.  Dynamic memory allocation, guaranteed to be contiguous.

Thanks for the info guys!

Comment: std::vector<char *> would offer a very simple, efficient solution.  Simply allocate a new char [] on each read and add it to the vector, then remove it when it's been parsed.

Comment: `other buffering I've done (image acquisition, tcp/ip), is that there we are guaranteed full packets/messages.` - you're not "guaranteed full packets/messages" in TCP/IP.

Comment: Oh, I guess I've always gotten lucky then.  I thought TCP/IP packets had a standard size, and full messages were constructed using those packets and algorithms like a sliding window.  I'll confess my only experience with TCP/IP was college projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define some 'APU' application-protocol-unit class that will represent your '[header]data[checksum]'.  Give it some 'add' function that takes a char parameter and returns a 'valid' bool.  In your serial read thread, create an APU and read some data into your 1024-byte buffer.  Iterate the data in the buffer, pushing it into the APU add() until either the APU add() function returns true or the iteration is complete.  If the add() returns true, you have a complete APU - queue it off for handling, create another one and start add()-ing the remaining buffer bytes to it. If the iteration is complete, loop back round to read more serial data.

The add() method would use a state-machine, or other mechanism, to build up and check the incoming bytes, returning 'true' only in the case of a full sanity-checked set of data with the correct checksum.  If some part of the checking fails, the APU is 'reset' and waits to detect a valid header.

The APU could maybe parse the data itself, either byte-by-byte during the add() data input, just before add() returns with 'true', or perhaps as a separate 'parse()' method called later, perhaps by some other APU-processing thread.

Comment: Oh - and James is right - TCP is a byte-streaming service like serial ports.  Your image-acquisition app may need some attention <g>  There is indeed a 'sliding-window' in the TCP protocol, but it's got nothing to do with application-level messages.

Comment: Great, I like this approach as well, thank you Martin!  And they were separate instances, image acquisition apps and TCP/IP.  My point was, in those instances, I always knew the message size and would just read a single message.  I'm still very new to a lot of these protocols (right word?).

Comment: @Constantin - yes, right word :)  I suppose I should add, for completeness, that continually creating new APU instances implies that 'used' ones should be disposed somewhere after they are 'used up', (or possibly released back to a pool of them, but that's more complex).

Comment: I've done ring buffers with the next "available" buffer being given before with images, I am assuming that's what you're implying.  The difficulty here is the APU's would be variable in size.

Comment: If the pool contains object references, they are all the same size :) An STL queue derivative could from the pool, (though it would have to be thread-safe and blocking, in the general case, since 'used' objects are unlikely to be always allocated/released to the pool from the same thread).  It is a good plan to try and design the internals of such pooled objects so as to require as little new/dispose/malloc/free as possible, so as to further reduce contention on the memory manager and reduce the chance of leaks.

Answer (score 0):

When reading from a serial port at speed, you typically need some kind of handshaking mechanism to control the flow of data.  This can be hardware (e.g. RTS/CTS), software (Xon/Xoff), or controlled by a higher level protocol.  If you're reading a large amount of data at speed without handshaking, your UART or serial controller needs to be able to read and buffer all the available data at that speed to ensure no data loss.  On 16550 compatible UARTs that you see on Windows PCs, this buffer is just 14 bytes, hence the need for handshaking or a real time OS.